# How can I force the singular table name on Rails scaffold generator?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scaffolding

I'm working with a legacy database and need to create some CRUD's. How can I use the `scaffold` generator and tell him the exact name of the table avoiding the pluralize process??

Also the tables are in spanish.

Comment: Check this but I dont recomend using scaffold http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html

Comment: Isn't the easiest way just to set the table name on each model? `self.table_name = 'name of legacy table'`

Comment: Yeah, I've also found something on the inflector, or the 'table_name' But there are like 50 tables, I'm looking for something like a config thing that I can write once... =P

Comment: Convention over configuration is the rails way. Why are you fighting the conventions?

Comment: `self.table_name` is the best way, if you have postgresql schemas/namespace for your tables, then I can show you how to set that up

Comment: @mohamed-el-mahallawy how would you do that with namespaces?

Comment: I guess `Namespace::table_name` ?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think you want

```
ActiveRecord::Base.pluralize_table_names = false
```

Found this here:

http://justinram.wordpress.com/2006/04/04/pluralize-table-names-no-thanks/

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3_1_release_notes.html

Comment: Upvote! I think this solution is better when you deal with multiple classes.

Answer (score 28):

You can just use ActiveRecord::Base.table_name= method to manually set the table name.

So, in your model you can do:

```
class OrderDetail < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = 'order_detail'
end
```

Comment: I like this one better because when one usually needs that is in a case of an exceptional class name. Your answer is a little bit misleading though. Table name is usually in `lowercase_separated_by_underscores` as found in `Schema.rb`. What you written is used for class names called `UpperCamelCase`.